# How to remove index.routing.allocation.include.tag in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added one include tag for my index in elsticsearch by executing below command.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings -d '{"index.routing.allocation.include.tag" : "tag1"}'
```

I don't see any command to unset/remove tag once set.
I can set tag to empty but I want to remove the tag property itself.

do we have any option to remove this tag, currently it is coming like this

```
{
"index": {
"creation_date": "1449858605286",
"routing": {
  "allocation": {
   "include": {
     "tag": ""
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Settings the property to empty is the correct way to do it.

Comment: but the tag name is not going away, as I mentioned above. I want to get rid of the name itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove shard allocation filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533361/remove-shard-allocation-filter)

Answer (score 2):

More recent Elasticsearch versions (5.0+ if I remember correctly) allow you to [unset configurations by setting them to `null`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html), for example:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec" : null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of the tag to an empty string will "unset" it but I'm afraid there is no way to "get rid" of the tag completely; you'll have to re-create the index. I've been bugged by this behavior too and found no other alternative.