# Remove shard allocation filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set a shard allocation filter like:

```
    PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : "node-1"
  }
}
```

How can I remove or disable such a setting? I tried with include, but then I have both filter setted - include and exclude. I can set something like `"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : ""`.

But is it also possible to set something like: `include all` nodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : null
  }
}
```

Sounds dumb, but I think that's how you unset things in elasticsearch...

Answer (score 8):

For the clusters running on Elasticsearch 5.x, you can pass `null` values to reset a setting. As said in this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22870), this is documented for [cluster level settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/cluster-update-settings.html) but not for the index level settings.

So you can do:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
   "transient" : {
       "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : null
   }
}
```

And also:

```
PUT test-index/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "routing": {
      "allocation": {
        "include": {
          "box_type": null
        },
        "exclude": {
          "box_type": null
        },
        "require": {
          "box_type": null
        },
        "total_shards_per_node": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To reset the include filter and include all nodes, you have to use both settings:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.include._name" : ""
  }
}
```

and

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
   "transient" : {
     "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : ""
   }
}
```